# Django get the value of a field in the __init__ of forms

Tags: python, django

I need to have the value of a field before doing an update.
forms.py

```
class Form_Rol(forms.ModelForm):
     class Model:
         model = My_Model
         fields = "__all__"

     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
         '''I want to do this'''
         value_coming_from_update = self.fields['name']
         print(value_coming_from_update)
```

Output....
<django.forms.fields.CharField object at 0x0000026649558DC0>
How do I print the actual value in init?

I can't use self.cleaned_data.get('name') in **init**. It gives me an error (AttributeError: 'Form_Rol' object has no attribute 'cleaned_data')

Answer (score 0):

`cleaned_data` does not exist until the form has been instantiated with data (a.k.a. "bound") and `is_valid()` has returned True. So it's fundamentally impossible for it to be accessed at `__init__` time.

Can you explain what you are trying to accomplish?

At a wild guess, you may be wanting to do further checking of a ModelForm-generated object before you save it. The way you do this is

```
if form.is_valid():
    instance = form.save( commit=False)
    # further checking of instance...
    if instance.ok_to_save():
        instance.save()
```

Comment: I needed to modify a data before saving it. I was able to do it with signals pre_save.
Thanks for the answer, it helped me understand something more about the form